# Count variation in the output

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, postgres-crosstab

```sql
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
   'SELECT request_address,CASE WHEN code = $$200$$ THEN $$success$$ ELSE $$failure$$
        END AS code,id,count(*) as count from table_1 group by 2,1,3 order by 2,1,3',
    $$VALUES (''),('306'),('308'),('309'),('310'),('311'),('312'),('313'),('314'),('315'),('316'),('317'),('NULL') $$)
 AS ct(request_address text,code text,"blank" bigint,"306" bigint,"308" bigint,"309" bigint,"310" bigint,"311" bigint,"312" bigint,"313" bigint,"314" bigint,"315" bigint,"316" bigint,"317" bigint,"null" bigint)
```

Due to incorrect grouping or ordering the code produces incorrect count and missing values in the output. It can be rectified by changing the grouping but I want to understand how it affects the output.

How to fix grouping or ordering for this query?

Comment: Please provide the exact `CREATE TABLE table_1 ...` statement.

Comment: Thank you erwin. But the below code eliminates some values.
Please find the table_1 attcahed

Comment: I don't see the table definition.

Comment: Attached table_1 below .


request | code | id  
---------|------|-----
 27.6    | 20   | 306 
 27.6    | 20   | 311 
 27.6    | 22   | 306 
 27.6    | 40   | 312 
 27.6    | 40   | 313 
 27.6    | 41   |     
 27.6    | 41   | 314 
 27.6    | 43   | 315 
 27.6    | 43   | 316 
 27.6    | 42   | 306 
 27.62   | 20   | 306 
 27.62   | 20   | 310 
 27.62   | 20   | 311 
 27.62   | 20   | 312 
 27.62   | 41   |     
 27.62   | 41   | 314 
 27.62   | 43   | 315 
 27.62   | 43   | 316 
 27.62   | 45   | 306 
 27.62   | 42   | 306

Comment: From the previous query you shared only the 1st combination of columns displays as output .For example,if 27.6 have 2 occurrences to be expected there comes only the 1st occurrence in the output

Answer (score 0):

For starters, input values must be sorted by the "row_name" (1st column).
And you cannot have `null` as "category" value.

This might work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
      $$
      SELECT request_address
            , CASE WHEN code = '200' THEN 'success' ELSE 'failure' END AS code
            , id
            , count(*)::int AS ct
      FROM    table_1
      GROUP   BY 1,2,3
      ORDER   BY 1,3     -- 1 has to be first!
      $$
    , $$SELECT unnest('{"",306,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317}'::text[])$$
   ) AS ct(request_address text, code text
         , "blank" int,"306" int,"308" int,"309" int,"310" int,"311" int,"312" int,"313" int,"314" int,"315" int,"316" int,"317" int);
```

But it's guesswork while the table definition is unknown.

Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)